# UV Editing problem when select all my character

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv, color

I'm new to blender and I am trying to do the owl tutorial on youtube. Unfortunately I have some problems with the UV Editing part. When I select every part individually it's look good in the UV editor. But when I select the entire character, it's look like these: [image] Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the UVs for some of the body parts are all funky! I bet there are some parts of the character that are getting missed when you select parts individually.

To start investigating, I recommend entering wireframe view, then selecting random parts of your character. Here I'm holding z, selecting "wireframe," and releasing z. This helps show parts of the model that may have been hidden before. Then I press c and start clicking and dragging on various parts of the model. I then hit right click to stop selecting. (You can hold Z and select "material view" to return to normal.)

[image: Video of me doing the process above to select random edges on a cube]

While doing this, keep an eye on the UV panel on the left. Hopefully this is enough to help you find which parts of the models have the weird UVs. Then you can choose just those body parts and UV unwrap those all over again.

My guess is that the talons have problems, since there is so much detail on them, and they're small, so it may be easy to miss any issues with the textures.

There may be weird hidden shapes elsewhere on the body too.

I also think those long stretchy rectangles on the left are from the parts of the face that have the "tv static" appearance, like this:

[image]

My reason for saying that is: that when UVs get stretched so big that they go outside the texture, they wrap around all over again (like when Pac-Man goes off the screen and comes back out the other side :p), and the texture gets smaller and smaller on the final model. Demonstration:

https://i.gyazo.com/96a92179b4e04d14c672a10fc631302d.gif

(Above: Gyazo video where I'm stretching the UVs beyond the boundaries of the texture. The final result in 3D is that the texture tiles and looks very tiny.)

Best of luck!